# Why is ggplot2 adding black lines on top of colored lines in geom_vline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add colored vertical lines (green) to a plot using geom_vline() function, but some black lines appear on top of green lines, sometimes at the border

[image]

```
exampleData <- structure(list(RT = c(136, 104.6, 117.7, 129.4, 122, 156.7, 37.3, 
                                     126, 41.8, 129, 110.1, 153.3, 28.9, 66, 43, 157.8, 116.2, 113.1, 
                                     83.5, 143.2, 39, 113.5, 94.8, 88.5, 77.8, 136.5, 64.9, 158.4, 
                                     45.8, 147.1, 127.7, 112, 120.4, 32.3, 146.6, 54.8, 148.8, 121.2, 
                                     36.8, 149.4, 67.1, 125.2, 115.1, 141.5, 129.9, 81.8, 121.6, 160, 
                                     46.3, 126.9), 
                              intensity = c(0.094, 0.74, 0.872, 0.337, 0.717, 
                                            0.003, 0.001, 0.527, 0.001, 0.361, 0.965, 0.003, 0, 0.033, 0.001, 
                                            0.003, 0.913, 0.985, 0.083, 0.015, 0.001, 1, 0.318, 0.151, 0.022, 
                                            0.082, 0.036, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.44, 0.956, 0.775, 0, 0.005, 
                                            0.162, 0.003, 0.764, 0.001, 0.003, 0.028, 0.569, 0.951, 0.024, 
                                            0.321, 0.058, 0.72, 0.004, 0.004, 0.489)), 
                         row.names = c(228L, 
                                       151L, 185L, 214L, 196L, 265L, 23L, 206L, 31L, 213L, 165L, 259L, 
                                       8L, 74L, 33L, 267L, 181L, 173L, 105L, 241L, 26L, 174L, 127L, 
                                       114L, 95L, 229L, 72L, 268L, 38L, 248L, 210L, 170L, 192L, 14L, 
                                       247L, 54L, 251L, 194L, 22L, 252L, 76L, 204L, 178L, 238L, 215L, 
                                       102L, 195L, 271L, 39L, 208L), 
                         class = "data.frame")

ggplot(exampleData , aes (x = RT, y = intensity)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(16, 17.5, 19, 20.5, 22, 23.5, 25, 26.5, 28)/0.2, 
             color="green", size = 1.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(60, 150))
```

I would like to have a plot with green lines without black lines on top.

Comment: You forgot to provide `EcFAIMS`. I ran the code and I don't see any black line on my screen

Comment: my appologies. Fixed

Comment: I am not seeing any black lines on top when I run that code. Are you referring to the black line above your plot? That looks like an artifact from taking a screen shot of your plot.

Comment: no I refer to the black lines within the green lines on the plot